# Google Cloud Dataprep - Scan for multiple input csv and create corresponding bigquery tables

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dataprep

I have several csv files on GCS which share the same schema but with different timestamps for example:

- data_20180103.csv
- data_20180104.csv
- data_20180105.csv

I want to run them through dataprep and create Bigquery tables with corresponding names. This job should be run everyday with a scheduler.

Right now what I think could work is as follows:

1. The csv files should have a timestamp column which is the same for every row in the same file
2. Create 3 folders on GCS: raw, queue and wrangled
3. Put the raw csv files into raw folder. A Cloud function is then run to move 1 file from raw folder into queue folder if it's empty, do nothing otherwise.
4. Dataprep scans the queue folder as per scheduler. If a csv file is found (eg. data_20180103.csv) the corresponding job is run, output file is put into wrangled folder (eg. data.csv).
5. Another Cloud function is run whenever a new file is added to wrangled folder. This one will create a new BigQuery table with name according to the timestamp column in csv file (eg. 20180103). It also delete all files in queue and wrangled folder and proceed to move 1 file from raw folder to queue folder if there's any.

Repeat until all tables are created.
This seems overly complicated to me and I'm not sure how to handle cases where the Cloud functions fail to do their job.

Any other suggestion for my use-case is appreciated.

Comment: Agree, it sounds very over-engineered. Why do you need Dataprep at all? How often will the files land in GCS? What is the source of the data files? A common pattern we use is: File -> GCS -> Cloud Function -> Dataflow (which is what Dataprep is using under the hood anyway) -> BigQuery. This pattern works really well.